# A function that takes a string and gives you the first word separated by whitespace?

Tags: erlang

Example: 
get_first("wassup! man") = "wassup!"

This must be very simple but can someone point me to a right direction of the solution. Not seen examples online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1>string:split("wassup! man", " ").
["wassup!","man"]
2> hd(string:split("wassup! man", " ")).
"wassup!"
```

or you can use http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#lexemes-2

Comment: thanks, I was trying sub_string and then saw your solution.

Answer (score 5):

I don't even know erlang, but Google is your friend! It would save yourself a lot of time if you try Googling your question before posting it here. Just try "erlang extract first word of string". The very first result will take you to this page: http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html where you can see the `sub_word` function. But then it says that this is deprecated and you need to use `nth_lexeme`:

http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#nth_lexeme-3

Comment: I think this is the best anwser, and possible faster than the accepted question.